# How to update view inside axios promise and after store dispatch?

Tags: vuejs2, axios

I have a simple vue app where I'm trying to add simple authentication. Inside my login.vue, I use axios to authenticate the user via ajax and store the token returned by the api in the store then redirect to a new page (ex: dashboard.vue).

The problem is that the token is saved but the view is not updated, can't call router.push() ...

Any ideas why isn't it working ? Thanks

Login.vue

```
methods: {
authenticate () {
  var dataLogin = {
    email: this.login,
    password: this.password
  }
  var headers = { headers: { 'Content-type': 'application/json', 'Accept': 'application/json' } }
  axios.post(config.apiUrl, dataLogin, headers)
  .then(response => {        
    this.$store.dispatch('login', response.data).then(() => {
      // if there is no error go to home page
      if (!this.$store.getters.error) {
        this.$router.push('/')
      }
    })
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.errorMessage = error.response.data.message
    this.authError = true
  })
}
```

}

The store function just save the token with localStorage

```
const actions = {
    login (context, data) {
        context.commit('authenticate', data)
    }
}
const mutations = {
    authenticate (state, data) {        
        localStorage.setItem('user-access_token', data.access_token)
    }
}
```

Comment: https://medium.com/@manojkumar_88220/role-based-authentication-using-vue-js-2-f54e18498019

Answer (score 0):

You are calling a `then()` handler when you dispatch the action.

But your action does not return a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

So return a promise  in your action as follows:

```
const actions = { 
    login (context, data) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            context.commit('authenticate', data) 
            resolve()
        }) 
    } 
}
```

Also chain your promises for better readability

```
axios.post(config.apiUrl, dataLogin, headers)
  .then(response => {        
    return this.$store.dispatch('login', response.data)
  }).then(() => {
      // if there is no error go to home page
      if (!this.$store.getters.error) {
        this.$router.push('/')
      }
  })
  .catch(error => {
    this.errorMessage = error.response.data.message
    this.authError = true
  })
```

Comment: Thank you @vamsi-krishna fro your response but semms like it's not working yet !

Comment: I don't have any errors but it does not simply refresh unless I force with ctrl-R

Comment: @PatrickRandria just remove the if check and try `this.$router.push('/')`